# Deploying a WPF Prism application using ClickOnce runs in to a generic error

Tags: wpf, clickonce, prism

I am trying to deploy a WPF Prism application using ClickOnce Deployment. I have followed the following steps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405497(v=pandp.40).aspx)

1. Publishing an Initial Version of the Shell Application
2. Updating the Manifests to Include Dynamically Loaded Module Assemblies - I have used Mage to include the dynamically loaded modules.

and then tried to launch and install the application but it runs in to a generic error.

"Application cannot be started. Contact the applicaiton vendor"

I am not running any other applications. I am running in to this error everytime I try to install the application. Please find the details from the log below.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [9/19/2011 4:22:20 PM] : Activation of http://localhost/ABCTools/ABCTools.Shell.application has started.
    * [9/19/2011 4:22:20 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/19/2011 4:22:20 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AA)
        - Source: System.Deployment

Comment: Is the Full Trust option selected? By default ClickOnce runs under Partial Trust

Comment: Rachel, Yes, the application is running in full trust mode.

Comment: Rachel,

Yes, the application is running in full trust mode.

Comment: Hi Rachel, Now I am getting the following errors when trying to install it on the client machine.
   + Exception reading manifest from http://f5f3zq1/PMTools/Application%20Files/PMechTools.Shell_1_0_0_4/PMechTools.Shell.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
  + The element 'dependentAssembly' in namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'assemblyIdentity' in namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2'.

Comment: Do they have the right version of the .Net framework installed?

Comment: The application is created using .NET 4.0. What are you referring to here? The client machine has .NET 4.0 installed

Comment: I have the same issue with the same king of app (WPF+PRISM+CASTLE). Everything works well under win7. I just updated some homemade  dll. Application works well just after the installation but failed to run after the next reboot (with the same COM error message).

Answer (score 0):

You should verify whether the installation fails the same on a different computer.  The exception you are getting is related to system corruption, possibly even of NGEN (in the .net framework).

http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0x800705AA

http://forums.asp.net/t/1502957.aspx/1